# How to get current Location when the app is running in background

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, gps, core-location

I want to get reference that, How can we find out current Latitude and Longitude when our application is running in background..

If you have any suggestion then please suggest me...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well first you need to tell iOS that your app will run in background with for retrieving the user location.

Do this by adding the `Required background modes` to the info.plist and set one item to `App registers for location updates`

The just set up the `CLLocationManager` to start monitoring location changes. 
Apple does suggest that your app only use `significant changes` to save battery: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW6

Comment: can didUpdateLocation method calls when app is running in background?

Comment: can we get new latitude and longitude? when location changes?

Comment: Yes it will get called if you set the `Required background modes` in the info.plist. read the apple documentation link I provided in my post.